# I need to create a 301 redirect in .htaccess for both a different domain and different directory structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I tried it using RedirectMatch but my code is not working. My syntax is probably incorrect.

Here's my code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^oldsite.com/guides/$ http://newsite.com/destinations/city-guides/
RedirectMatch 301 ^oldsite.com/show/$ http://newsite.com/tv-show/concept/
RedirectMatch 301 ^oldsite.com/destinations/$ http://newsite.com/tv-show/concept/
RedirectMatch 301 ^oldsite.com/concept.html http://newsite.com/tv-show/concept/
RedirectMatch 301 ^oldsite.com/format.html http://newsite.com/tv-show/format/
RedirectMatch 301 ^oldsite.com/about.html http://newsite.com/about/
RedirectMatch 301 ^oldsite.com/contact.html http://newsite.com/contact/
```

The first three lines I want any file in those old directories to go to the root of the new directory. The last four are specific page to page redirects.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't match domain name in `RedirectMatch`. Only request URI is matched.

Try this on old site's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^guides/$ http://newsite.com/destinations/city-guides/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^show/$ http://newsite.com/tv-show/concept/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^destinations/$ http://newsite.com/tv-show/concept/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^concept.html http://newsite.com/tv-show/concept/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^format.html http://newsite.com/tv-show/format/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about.html http://newsite.com/about/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^contact.html http://newsite.com/contact/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava but the old site is parked now so there's no .htaccess file to modify. Strange host (Pair.com) you park on top of another domain, which basically acts as a mirror. Anyway I need a different solution.

Comment: Why did you not provide this information in question? See updated code, it should be placed in the .htaccess  wherever it is parked (create it if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear I was referencing the htaccess file on the new server. I will try your solution.